# S3 sink custom timezone offset

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set up a custom timezone offset for my S3 sink connector.

What I'm trying to achieve is that every morning at 04:00 AM UTC I wanna start a new day.

Example:

The current date & time is: 06-09-2022 01:00 am UTC

Kafka S3 sink connector needs to dump data into:
s3:////year=2022/month=06/**day=09**/

The current date & time is: 06-09-2022 04:00 am UTC

Kafka S3 sink connector needs to dump data into a new folder ( new day )
s3:////year=2022/month=06/**day=10**/

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8083/connectors' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "sink-s3-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "test_topic",
        "s3.region": "us-east-1",
        "s3.bucket.name": "my-bucket",
        "aws.accessKeyId": "mock-key",
        "aws.secretKey": "mock-key",
        "data.format": "AVRO",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "flush.size": 1,
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "s3.proxy.url": "http://localstack:4572",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "timezone": "'[+]18:00'",
        "timestamp.extractor": "Wallclock"
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The timezones must be Java implementations, not numeric offsets. These are JVM specific, and there is no `+18:00` offset, only `UTC-6`, such as  `"Etc/GMT+6"`

Another alternative is to implement a custom transform that forwards your timestamp +**20** hours since 0400 would become 0000 of the following day, whereas 18 hours would be 2200 hour of the same day.